# Extension of group and direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$, $E$ and $G$ be groups, and suppose we have a short exact sequence of these groups:
$$1\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{i} E \xrightarrow{\pi} G\rightarrow 1.$$
Assume $\exists$ homomorphisms $p:G\rightarrow E , q:E\rightarrow A$ such that corresponding compositions on $A$ and $G$ are $1$:
$$\pi\circ p=1_G, \,\,\,\, q\circ i=1_A.$$
**Claim:** $E$ is isomorphic to direct product of $A$ and $G$.

This could be very trivial, but I am missing somewhere my argument. I did following:

Define $\varphi:E\rightarrow A\times G$  by $\varphi(x)=(q(x),\pi(x))$.

Easy to show that $\varphi$ is injective and homomorphism.

> **Q.** I failed to show surjectivity of $\varphi$. In surjectivity, I was facing problem to show that the composition $G\xrightarrow{p} E\xrightarrow{q} A$ is trivial map i.e. $q\circ p(x)=1$ for all $x\in G$. How do we proceed for *this step*?

There could be alternate ways; but I am trying to find gap/mistake in my above approach.

Comment: You don't need the map $p$. The existence of $q$ is enough to imply that $G = i(A) \times \ker(q)$ and then $i(A) \cong A$ and $\ker(q) \cong E/i(A) \cong G$. The map $p$ by itself would tell you that $E$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product $A \rtimes G$.